# Adding a new edge loop doesn't work on some parts

Tags: edges

Sometimes i try to add a new edge loop but than it doesn't go all the way around. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? I am using a Mirror modifier. And sometimes i like to delete a line by using x and than disolve edge. Or is this the problem?
Picture:
[image: The picture]

Thanks for helping in advanced.

Comment: It's because you have an ngon.

Comment: You can only loopcut quads; You have a n-gon, a pentagon to be more precise, in your model.

Comment: Cheers for helping its solved :)